# C3JS redraw when DIV is resized

Tags: jquery, c3.js

I'm using a simple JQuery and CSS method to resize one of my chart DIV's when you click the DIV. The DIV is resized to 100% of the page.

A sample is here (or check my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmerd/837q5zr9/2/)):

```js
$('.col-sm-6').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
  });
```

```css
.col-sm-6 {
   width: 68%;
   transition: width 2s !important;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: #ffffff;
  }
  .col-sm-6.clicked {
   z-index: 9999; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100%; 
   position: fixed; 
   top: 25px; 
   left: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" style="border:1px solid black">CLICK</div>
```

How do I go about resizing the chart svg, which is contained within the "col-sm-6" DIV in the example above, when the DIV is resized (and back again)? It seems like the only time it is resized is when the actual browser window changes, not just the DIV.

Would I use the `onresize()` function in C3JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use c3.js API **[.resize()](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-resize)** method:

```
chart.resize({
  height: 640,
  width: 480
});
```

See [example](http://c3js.org/samples/api_resize.html) here.

---

You mentioned **onresize()** - this is callback on webpage resize only, and it **does not** fire after .resize()

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this same issue in the future, here is my solution:

```
$('#resize').on('click', function(){
   setTimeout(function () {
      chart5.resize({
        height: $("#election-stat-chart-05").height(),
        width: $("#election-stat-chart-05").width()
      });
    }, 500);
});
```

See the snippet below:

```js
$(function () {

    // Initial chart
    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            columns: [
                ['data1', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50],
                ['data2', 200, 130, 90, 240, 130, 220],
                ['data3', 300, 200, 160, 400, 250, 250]
            ],
            type: 'bar'
        },
        bindto: '#election-stat-chart-05',
    });
 
    $('#resize').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            chart.resize({
                height: $("#election-stat-chart-05").height(),
                width: $("#election-stat-chart-05").width()
            });
        }, 500);
    });
});
/*-------------------*/
$('#resize').on('click', function(){
    $('.col-sm-6').toggleClass('resize');           
});
```

```css
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 68%;
  /*transition: width 1s !important;*/
}
.col-sm-6.resize {
  z-index: 9999; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 300px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 25%; 
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="chart-05">
    <div class="keen-dataviz">
      <div class="keen-dataviz-title">Absentee Ballots by Precinct
        <div style="float:right;"><a id="resize">CLICK TO RESIZE</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="keen-dataviz-stage">
        <div id="election-stat-chart-05" style="margin-right: 10px; max-height: 223px; position: relative;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshmerd/837q5zr9/).